# What is the difference between html.EscapeString() and template.HTMLEscapeString()?

Tags: html, go, escaping

I need to escape some html and want to make sure I am not missing anything.

The "html" package has:

```
[html.EscapeString(s string) string][1]
which will escape `'"&<>`
```

The "text/template" package has:

```
[template.HTMLEscapeString(s string) string][2]
which also escapes `'"&<>`
```

They seem to do the same but have slightly different approaches. Is there any differences that I am missing? If not, why 2 different built-in functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. Internally they are differently implemented ([[1]](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/html/escape.go#L166) [[2]](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/text/template/funcs.go#L489)) but results are 100% equal.

I'm pretty sure `HTMLEscapeString` was created for internal `text/template` package usage so if you need to escape HTML in your app just use `html.EscapeString`.